# Trying to solve 'Call to a member function all() on null' when accessing relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Working with this for several hours by now, so any help would be appreciated. I created a new model in Laravel with a One-To-One relation to another Model (Survey - SurveyLifecycle).
Survey method to access relation:

```
protected function lifecycle(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\SurveyLifecycle');
    }
```

SurveyLifecycle contains several timestamps, that are filled when Survey status changes. One method for example:

```
/**
     * @return void
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    public function markOfferFormation(): void
    {
        $this->assertStatus(self::STATUS_DECISION_DONE);
        if (!$this->creditor || !$this->creditor->isFilled()) {
            throw new DomainException('Creditor is not filled');
        }

        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $this->status = self::STATUS_OFFER_FORMATION;
            $this->lifecycle->markOfferFormationAt();
            $this->save();
            DB::commit();
        } catch (Throwable $exception) {
            DB::rollBack();
            throw $exception;
        }
    }
```

SurveyLifecycle is inserted into the database after creating the Survey model through boot() method. But the problem is, when I am trying to access 'lifecycle' property in controllers or views (like this)

```
/**
         * @var Survey $survey
         */
        $survey = Survey::findOrFail($id);
        dd($survey->lifecycle);
```

I get the error 'Call to a member function all() on null', even though I am sure, that there is a SurveyLifecycle entry in the database corresponding to this Survey model (manually inserted it to check). When I am trying to query raw data from database, the data for SurveyLifecycle is there:
[image: Database entry]

So the main question is - what am I missing?

Comment: Isn't the problem that your relation is defined as `protected` rather than `public`?

Comment: No, because I am trying to access the property, not the relation itself. It works fine on my other properties

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your relation as `protected`. In first snippet you are accesing relation data inside the same class `$this->lifecycle`, but `$survey->lifecycle` is call outside your class.

You should probably define it as `public`:

```php
public function lifecycle(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\SurveyLifecycle');
    }
```

Comment: I am accessing the property, not the relation